# How to use the `mt` command in linux to extract a file quickly in a tape drive by first moving the drive head to the general location?

Tags: linux, tar

I am currently trying to use the `tar` and `mt` command in Linux to take out files on a tape. The problem is that sometimes I get errors about files that were not able to be retrieved. When I try to retrieve a specific file, with:

```
sudo tar -C 'destination/folder' -xvof /dev/st0 'path/to/file/in/tape'
```

the drive will go one by one from start to finish to see where the file is. If I know that the file is towards the end, this is cumbersome as it seems easier to first fast forward to the end, then try to extract the files. Is there a way to make the drive go to go to general locations on the tape using `mt`? I looked in the manual but only found something like `eod` (end of drive), but not general quadrants of the tape (1st half, 2nd half, etc). Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `tar`work. Do not forget the name of the command come from "Tape ARchive". Think about the tape as sequence of records and the records are accessed consecutive. SO even if you use some `mt`command you will do the same process (reading all the files)